# Sending ajax form reloads page instead of sending request

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm struggling to create a shoutbox for django. Everything works fine now concerning reading data from the database, but when I want to add a new shout the whole page is being reloaded, and from what I was able to check - form's action remains the same, and there is no request sent to function under specified url. What am I doing wrong here ?

HTML :

```
<div id="shoutbox">    
    <form method="post" id="form" class="shoutbox-form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>User</label></td>
                <td><input class="text user" id="nick" type="text" MAXLENGTH="25" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Message</label></td>
                <td><input class="text" id="shout" type="text" MAXLENGTH="255" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input id="send-shout" type="submit" value="Dodaj!" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="shoutbox-container">
        <span class="clear"></span>
        <div class="shoutbox">
            <div id="shoutbox-loading"><img src="css/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputUser = $("#nick");
    var inputMessage = $("#shout");
    var loading = $("#shoutbox-loading");
    var messageList = $(".shoutbox > ul");

    function updateShoutbox(){
        messageList.hide();
        loading.fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "/shouts/", 
            data: "action=refresh",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                loading.fadeOut();
                var c = data["response"];
                messageList.html(c);
                messageList.fadeIn(2000);
            }
        });
    }
    function checkForm(){
        if(inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    updateShoutbox();


    $("#shoutbox-form").submit(function(){
        if(checkForm()){
            var nick = inputUser.attr("value");
            var message = inputMessage.attr("value");
            $("#send-shout").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });
            $("#send-shout").blur();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                async: true,
                url: "/shouts/", 
                data: "action=insert&user=" + nick + "&message=" + message,
                //data: {"action" : "insert", "user": user, "message": message},
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function(data){
                    var c = data["response"];
                    messageList.html(c);
                    updateShoutbox();
                    $("#send-shout").attr({ disabled:false, value:"Shout!" });
                }
             });
        }
        else alert("All fields needed!");
        return false;
    });    
});
```

My url :

```
url(r'^shouts/?$', "shoutbox"),
```

And function :

```
def shoutbox(request, user=None, message=None):
    response = ""
    if not request.POST.get("action"):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        req = request.POST.get("action")
        if req == "insert":
            response = shoutbox_add(message, user)
        elif req == "refresh":
            response = shoutbox_get(20)

    if request.is_ajax():
        result = simplejson.dumps({
            'response': response
        }, cls=LazyEncoder)
        return HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has id 'form' and class 'shoutbox-form', so your selector should be

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
```

or

```
$(".shoutbox-form").submit(function(){
```

Comment: Nice find, good sir. Also, mastodon...before you kill yourself over these types of things in the future, start at the beginning of the problem. Before I saw sje397's comment, I was going to tell you to do a simple alert('test'); return false; at the top of that function to test if it's even getting there. You can usually isolate problems like this one by starting with the obvious (i.e., is it even getting to the function?).